# Data Reader Initialization (again)

Tags: c#

I am getting a datareader initialization error. I know that this has been answered many times before but those cases don't seem to fit my situation. The error message begins "Execute Reader: Connection property has not been initialized."

The program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BookList   

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
            dataConnection.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = BIBLIOGRAPHY;Data Source = JBSHAPIRO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";

            dataConnection.Open();
            Console.Write("Enter author's name: ");
            string person = Console.ReadLine();




            SqlCommand datacommand = new SqlCommand();
            datacommand.CommandText = "SELECT AUTHOR, TITLE, YEAR, KEYWORDS 

FROM BOOKS WHERE AUTHOR = ' " + person + " ' ";


            Console.WriteLine("About to Execute: {0}\n\n", 

datacommand.CommandText);


            SqlDataReader dataReader = datacommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                string author1 = dataReader.GetString(0);
                string title1 = dataReader.GetString(1);
                int year1 = dataReader.GetInt32(2);
                string keywords1 = dataReader.GetString(3);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Author: {0}\n, Title: {1}\n, Year: {2}\n; Key Words: {4)\n\n",
                author1, title1, year1, keywords1);
                dataReader.Close();
            }
            dataConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The code works with a different database written for C# 3 but I am now trying to use C# 6.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting to know why question with badly formatted code and unlikely correct statement about "The code works with a different database written for C# 3" got so many upvotes. I see how question with [MCVE] could be ok (and without SQL injection)...

Answer (score 3):

You never associated the `SqlCommand` with the connection:

```
SqlCommand datacommand = new SqlCommand();
datacommand.Connection = dataConnection;
```

Without it, the command (and by extension the data reader) has no knowledge of any connection to use.

Comment: This can't be really answer (even if it is completely correct) as "The code works with a different database written for C# 3"... Not sure how to vote now.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: My guess is that statement about the code working elsewhere is likely mistaken.  Very *similar* code may "work" in another context entirely.  But the exact code in the question would produce the error in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You do

```
SqlCommand datacommand = new SqlCommand();
```

But I don't see a

```
datacommand.Connection = dataConnection;
```

This way neither the command nor the SqlDataReader knows what connection to use.

Side note: I would stronly advice to add parameters over dynamic SQL.

This is a good start to prevent Sql Injection

```
SqlCommand datacommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT AUTHOR, TITLE, YEAR, KEYWORDS FROM BOOKS WHERE AUTHOR = @AUTHOR", dataConnection);

datacommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUTHOR", person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers.  Actually the program comes from Microsoft Press's C# 2008 Step By  Step. It does work with that old version of C#. 
after submitting the question I  noticed that that the newer specification you do need to specify the connection in the SQL statement.

I thank you all for your help.
silenus